# New User in Hyperledger Fabric Node.js SDK

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have followed [Writing your first application](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/write_first_app.html) to setup a sample node.js app for fabric v1. The provided sample app (fabcar) works fine. I want to run this app with the Network set up with [First Network guide](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html). The provided query.js/invoke.js uses ***-priv and ***-pub keys in these files to use queries as UserAdmin.
 `hfc.newDefaultKeyValueStore({ path: options.wallet_path });`
Can any one help me to hook up this node.js sdk with other networks and how to generate these `-pub` and `-priv` files for other user??

I am a beginner with hyperledger/blockchain so any other details and steps that i am missing???